# Bootstrap Password input Toggle Function not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my HTML Form :-

```
<input name="inputPassword" type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password.."><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></span>
```

And here is my try with Jquery [I am not Jquery Student :(]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".icon-eye-open").click(function(){
    $('.icon-eye-open').removeClass('icon-eye-open').addClass('icon-eye-close');
    document.getElementById("inputPassword").setAttribute('type', 'text');
});

$(".icon-eye-close").click(function(){
    $('.icon-eye-close').removeClass('icon-eye-close').addClass('icon-eye-open');
    document.getElementById("inputPassword").setAttribute('type', 'password');
});

</script>
```

So, you might have guessed, what i am trying to do. I am actually trying to replace class of clicked class [toggle-ing between class] and than trying to change attribute from password to text and vice versa.

And this is not Working.

Here is jsfiddle demo :- http://jsfiddle.net/gR5FH/

Can you please suggest / help me find my mistake.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".icon-eye-open").on("click", function() {
$(this).toggleClass("icon-eye-close");
var type = $("#inputPassword").attr("type");
if (type == "text")
{ $("#inputPassword").attr("type", "password");}
else
{ $("#inputPassword").attr("type", "text"); }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the element `$(".icon-eye-close")` does not exist when you start listening the `click` event, so that code never runs. You can prevent this by using an unique event handler for the `click` and then toggle classes and input type within it.

Try this HTML:

```
<input name="inputPassword" type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password...">
<span class="add-on">
    <i id="visibilitySwitch" class="icon-eye-close"></i>
</span>
```

With this JS:

```
$("#visibilitySwitch").click(function(){
    $(this)
        .toggleClass('icon-eye-open')
        .toggleClass('icon-eye-close');
    if ($('#inputPassword').attr('type') == 'password')
        $('#inputPassword').attr('type', 'text')
    else
        $('#inputPassword').attr('type', 'password')
});
```

Comment: Well I already voted above reply my answer. But really many thanks for your reply too.. I am learning jquery slowly through all you guys. Thanks a lot once again.